# PHP Comparação entre campos

Tags: php

Boas,

Eu estou a fazer um systema de comentários, mas estou tendo problemas,
Como faço uma verificação entre dois campos.

```
$postcomment = $_POST['message'];
$uploaded = $_POST['upload'];
```

Por exemplo, se o "utilizador" apenas postar o campo $postcomment e se postar acima de 20 caracteres, passa,

Ou

Se postar o campo $uploaded, e se esse campo começar por http://, passa.

Como faço esta comparação?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar `if's` para a verificação, segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
if (strlen($postcomment) >= 20 && empty($uploaded)) {
    // Veririca se o campo $postcomment tem mais de 20 caracteres e se o campo $uploaded esta vazio
} else if (!empty($uploaded) && preg_match('/^http:\/\//', $uploaded)) {
  // Verifica se o campo $uploaded não esta vazio e se começa com "http://"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o `mb_strlen` para saber quantos caracteres possui e compare com o número minimo de caracteres exigidos.

Por exemplo:

```
if(mb_strlen($postcomment) > MINIMO_DE_CARACTERES && !isset($uploaded)){
     $passa = true;
}
```

Para saber se começa com `http` você pode usar REGEX, basta lembrar que URLs podem, começar com o `http` quanto com `https`, portanto poderá utilizar:

```
/^(http|https):\/\//
```

Logo:

```
if(preg_match('/^(http|https):\/\//', $uploaded) && !isset($postcomment)){
     $passa = true;
}
```

---

Você não diz o que deve ocorrer se ambos forem preenchidos, esta é uma situação que deve ser tratada, enfim isto seria uma solução:

```
if((!empty($postcomment) ^ !empty($uploaded))
   && (mb_strlen($postcomment) > 20 || preg_match('/^(http|https):\/\//', $uploaded))){

    $passa = true;

}
```

[Teste isto aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6e69b95695a31bc366cbfce84eda1e6a666d1a4d)

A utilização do `xor` (`^`)  irá fazer com que apenas se o `$uploaded` ou o `$postcomment` forem preenchidos, porém não ambos, neste caso se ambos forem preenchidos "não irá continuar".